# Connect to localhost slave node from Jenkins docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins

I do want to connect my **Jenkins master slave** in a docker container to my **localhost machine node slave**(to be accurate my macOS High Sierra). 
Here you are the steps I followed:

1. Run `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts`.
2. Go to **Manage Jenkins**. Click on **Manage Nodes**.
3. Launch method, select: **Launch slave agents on Unix machines via SSH**
4. Host: 192.168.1.33, 127.0.0.1, localhost, 0.0.0.0
5. Credentials: **Username and password** or **SSH username with private key**.

I don't know what ip I should put in the Host field and which option to select in Credentials field. I've already tried several combinations but I don't get any result. In addition, when I make a ping from my container to my localhost, it is always successful.

How Can I setup the Host and Credentials fields in order to connect to my local host node slave without having to use the **Launch slave agents via Java Web Start**
I always get this error:

```
SSHLauncher{host='192.168.1.33', port=22, credentialsId='4bc9a817-edae-4806-bc55-2f5b4f5b03e7', jvmOptions='', javaPath='', prefixStartSlaveCmd='', suffixStartSlaveCmd='', launchTimeoutSeconds=210, maxNumRetries=10, retryWaitTime=15, sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy=hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.KnownHostsFileKeyVerificationStrategy, tcpNoDelay=true, trackCredentials=true}
[09/23/18 21:24:39] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 192.168.1.33:22.
Connection refused (Connection refused)
SSH Connection failed with IOException: "Connection refused (Connection refused)", retrying in 15 seconds.  There are 10 more retries left.
Connection refused (Connection refused)
SSH Connection failed with IOException: "Connection refused (Connection refused)", retrying in 15 seconds.  There are 8 more retries left.
Connection refused (Connection refused)
SSH Connection failed with IOException: "Connection refused (Connection refused)", retrying in 15 seconds.  There are 9 more retries left.
Connection refused (Connection refused)
SSH Connection failed with IOException: "Connection refused (Connection refused)", retrying in 15 seconds.  There are 7 more retries left.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your slave node listening on port 22 for SSH connections ?

- If yes, are you able to telnet 192.168.1.33 22 from Jenkins master ?
- If no, install a basic SSH server on your slave node like open
  openssh and try again ?

Answer (score 0):

I just got this working with a Jenkins Docker container with my mac as the slave node.

For the Host field enter the output of the "hostname" command when you run it on terminal. To set the credential field, make a Jenkins credential with your username and password for your mac (whatever credential works when you run ssh localhost on terminal).

I also have the field "Host Key Verification Strategy" set to "non verifying Verification Strategy." But you may not need this if you manually run the ssh command on your terminal and accept the key